# method call with a code block in an IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I am returning an IQueryable to a controller which will call Kendo's *toDataSource()* method which looks after my filters, sorts, groupings etc:

```
public IQueryable<NcEntityDto> GetEntityIQueryableForKendoGrid()
{
    var userId = AbpSession.UserId;
    var query = (from e in _ncEntityRepository.GetAll()
        .Include(m => m.CarePlans)
        .Include(m => m.Warnings)
                    join o1 in _organizationUnitRepository.GetAll() on e.OrganizationUnitId equals o1.Id
                    join u1 in _userOrganizationUnitRepository.GetAll().Where(m => m.UserId == userId) on o1.Id equals u1.OrganizationUnitId

                    select new NcEntityDto()
                    {
                        Id = e.Id,
                        DisplayName = e.DisplayName,
                        CreationTime = e.CreationTime,
                        ExtensionData = e.ExtensionData,
                        OrganizationUnitDisplayName = o1.DisplayName,
                        CarePlanSectionsForReviewCount = e.CarePlans.Where(cp => cp.ReviewDatetime.HasValue && cp.ReviewDatetime < Clock.Now).Count(),
                        CarePlanSectionsReviewedCount = e.CarePlans.Where(cp => cp.ReviewDatetime.HasValue && cp.ReviewDatetime >= Clock.Now).Count(),
                        WarningCount = e.Warnings.Count()
                    })
        .AsQueryable();
    return query;
}
```

I want to build OrganisationDisplayName with a method which reads the upline tree and builds me a breadcrumb:

```
public string GetOrganisationUnitBreadcrumbSync(long input)
{
    var breadcrumbList = new List<string>(); ;
    var ncOrganizationUnit = _organizationUnitRepository.FirstOrDefault(input);

    while (ncOrganizationUnit != null)
    {
        breadcrumbList.Add(ncOrganizationUnit.DisplayName);
        ncOrganizationUnit = _organizationUnitRepository.FirstOrDefault(Convert.ToInt64(ncOrganizationUnit.ParentId));
    }
    breadcrumbList.Reverse();
    return string.Join(" - ", breadcrumbList);
}
```

As soon as I add the method to the IQueryable:

```
OrganizationUnitDisplayName = GetOrganisationUnitBreadcrumbSync(o1.Id)
```

I get a runtime error from entity framework -

> a second operation started on this context

I have tried to invoke the method call as async by using invoke and I can find no way of extending my queryable by using a code block in an expression function.  The breadcrumb facilitates the "*group by*" functionality of the grid so I can not iterate the data set after the *toDataSource()* call.  Any ideas how I can facilitate a method call with a code block in an IQueryable without causing second call problems on the underlying context?

Comment: From my experience this happens when you combine async and sync calls. Are you doing an Async call somewhere else in your code that might be conflicting here?

Comment: @Immorality Yep, that's what I thought but the controller uses a non-async method.  But it is perhaps worth asking Telerik (or Progress or whatever they're called nowadays) if the toDataSource() method uses async calls.  That would maybe explain the problem.